# String.equals(StringBuilder) and StringBuilder.equals(String) Confusion

Tags: string, java-8, stringbuilder

So I am given this piece of code and asked the question: What will be the result of compiling and executing Test class.

```
package com.foo.bar; 

public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String str = "java";
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("java");

         System.out.println(str.equals(sb) + ":" + sb.equals(str));
     }
}
```

The result according to them and the program when run through Eclipse is

```
false:false
```

I do not understand why it gives the above output. I thought String class overrides .equals so that it converts the values into strings and compares them. i.e. :

```
Object b, Object c -> 
b.equals(c) ->
b.toString.equals(c.toString()) //b is a String
```

It is running the `String.equals()`. If you have `str -> "java"` and `sb -> "java"` which both override toString.

```
str.equals(sb) -> str.toString().equals(b.toString) -> true
```

Comment: Why would a `StringBuilder` object equal a `String` object?

Comment: @GBlodgett because it toStrings them

Comment: Why would `String.equals` perform `toString()` on an object?

Comment: @rgettman Because when you do '(new String("foo").equals(new String("foo")) -> (new String("foo")).toString().equals(new String("foo").toString())'

Comment: Calling `toString` on a `String` object does absolutely nothing. If you look at the source code it just returns itself

Comment: @Gblodgett because then it is raw...

Comment: @Gblodgett raw and then won't compare the references... otherwise would .equals simply compare the refs... which would almost always false.

Comment: equals() belongs String class, But when the object of StringBuilder/StringBuffer is passing references are compared because StringBuffer does not override equals method of Object class.

Comment: @gmanrocks No, it checks to see if it is a `String`. If it isn't then it returns false. If it is, then it casts it and checks to see if the contents of the `String` is equal

Comment: @KoustubhMadkaikar stringbuilder*

Comment: @GBlodgett followup question, will StringBuilder do the same process... check if it is not a stringbuilder and if it is not go false?

Comment: @gmanrocks `StringBuilder` actually does not override `.equals` so it will have the default `.equals` from the `Object` class

Comment: @GBlodgett oh yeh right forgot xD dumb question.

Comment: For what it's worth the implementation of `String.equals` is on line 974 [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [`String.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) does not convert the other argument to a `String` then compare the characters.

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is `true` if and only if the argument is not `null` and is a `String` object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

If the other object is not a `String`, e.g. a `StringBuilder`, then it will always return `false`.  It will *not* convert the object to a `String`.

Like any well-formed `equals` method, it will test if the given object is the same class (ensuring it's not `null` first), and if it is, cast it to a `String`, but it won't call `toString` or otherwise convert the given object to a `String`.

Comment: As an addendum, you can use [`contentEquals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contentEquals-java.lang.CharSequence-) to check whether a `String` has the same content as a `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, or `CharBuffer`, etc.